# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT in my weather App

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I am trying to make an API call to open-meteo.com API each time I run my app I get the an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

I have checked several answers but they don't match my code.

```
data class WeatherDataDto(
    @field:SerializedName( "time")
    val time: List<String>,
    @field:SerializedName("temperature_2m")
    val temperatures: List<Double>,
    @field:SerializedName("weathercode")
    val weatherCodes: List<Int>,
    @field:SerializedName("pressure_msl")
    val pressures: List<Double>,
    @field:SerializedName("relativehumidity_2m")
    val humidities: List<Double>,
    @field:SerializedName( "windspeed_10m")
    val windSpeeds: List<Double>,
)
```

This is my API class:

```
interface WeatherApi {
   @GET("v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&hourly=temperature_2m,weathercode,relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_10m,pressure_msl")
   suspend fun getWeatherData(
       @Query("latitude") lat:Double,
       @Query("longitude") long:Double
   ):WeatherDto
}


"hourly": {
"time": [
  "2023-10-16T00:00",
  "2023-10-16T01:00",
  "2023-10-16T02:00",
  "2023-10-16T03:00",
  "2023-10-16T04:00",
  "2023-10-16T05:00",
  "2023-10-16T06:00",
  "2023-10-16T07:00",
  "2023-10-16T08:00",
  "2023-10-16T09:00",
  "2023-10-16T10:00",
  "2023-10-16T11:00",
  "2023-10-16T12:00",
  "2023-10-16T13:00",
  "2023-10-16T14:00",
  "2023-10-16T15:00",
  "2023-10-16T16:00",
  "2023-10-16T17:00",
  "2023-10-16T18:00",
  "2023-10-16T19:00",
  "2023-10-16T20:00",
  "2023-10-16T21:00",
  "2023-10-16T22:00",
  "2023-10-16T23:00",
  "2023-10-17T00:00",
  "2023-10-17T01:00",
  "2023-10-17T02:00",
  "2023-10-17T03:00",
  "2023-10-17T04:00",
  "2023-10-17T05:00",
  "2023-10-17T06:00",
  "2023-10-17T07:00",
  "2023-10-17T08:00",
  "2023-10-17T09:00",
  "2023-10-17T10:00",
  "2023-10-17T11:00",
  "2023-10-17T12:00",
  "2023-10-17T13:00",
  "2023-10-17T14:00",
  "2023-10-17T15:00",
  "2023-10-17T16:00",
  "2023-10-17T17:00",
  "2023-10-17T18:00",
  "2023-10-17T19:00",
  "2023-10-17T20:00",
  "2023-10-17T21:00",
  "2023-10-17T22:00",
  "2023-10-17T23:00",
  "2023-10-18T00:00",
  "2023-10-18T01:00",
  "2023-10-18T02:00",
  "2023-10-18T03:00",
  "2023-10-18T04:00",
  "2023-10-18T05:00",
  "2023-10-18T06:00",
  "2023-10-18T07:00",
  "2023-10-18T08:00",
  "2023-10-18T09:00",
  "2023-10-18T10:00",
  "2023-10-18T11:00",
  "2023-10-18T12:00",
  "2023-10-18T13:00",
  "2023-10-18T14:00",
  "2023-10-18T15:00",
  "2023-10-18T16:00",
  "2023-10-18T17:00",
  "2023-10-18T18:00",
  "2023-10-18T19:00",
  "2023-10-18T20:00",
  "2023-10-18T21:00",
  "2023-10-18T22:00",
  "2023-10-18T23:00",
  "2023-10-19T00:00",
  "2023-10-19T01:00",
  "2023-10-19T02:00",
  "2023-10-19T03:00",
  "2023-10-19T04:00",
  "2023-10-19T05:00",
  "2023-10-19T06:00",
  "2023-10-19T07:00",
  "2023-10-19T08:00",
  "2023-10-19T09:00",
  "2023-10-19T10:00",
  "2023-10-19T11:00",
  "2023-10-19T12:00",
  "2023-10-19T13:00",
  "2023-10-19T14:00",
  "2023-10-19T15:00",
  "2023-10-19T16:00",
  "2023-10-19T17:00",
  "2023-10-19T18:00",
  "2023-10-19T19:00",
  "2023-10-19T20:00",
  "2023-10-19T21:00",
  "2023-10-19T22:00",
  "2023-10-19T23:00",
  "2023-10-20T00:00",
  "2023-10-20T01:00",
  "2023-10-20T02:00",
  "2023-10-20T03:00",
  "2023-10-20T04:00",
  "2023-10-20T05:00",
  "2023-10-20T06:00",
  "2023-10-20T07:00",
  "2023-10-20T08:00",
  "2023-10-20T09:00",
  "2023-10-20T10:00",
  "2023-10-20T11:00",
  "2023-10-20T12:00",
  "2023-10-20T13:00",
  "2023-10-20T14:00",
  "2023-10-20T15:00",
  "2023-10-20T16:00",
  "2023-10-20T17:00",
  "2023-10-20T18:00",
  "2023-10-20T19:00",
  "2023-10-20T20:00",
  "2023-10-20T21:00",
  "2023-10-20T22:00",
  "2023-10-20T23:00",
  "2023-10-21T00:00",
  "2023-10-21T01:00",
  "2023-10-21T02:00",
  "2023-10-21T03:00",
  "2023-10-21T04:00",
  "2023-10-21T05:00",
  "2023-10-21T06:00",
  "2023-10-21T07:00",
  "2023-10-21T08:00",
  "2023-10-21T09:00",
  "2023-10-21T10:00",
  "2023-10-21T11:00",
  "2023-10-21T12:00",
  "2023-10-21T13:00",
  "2023-10-21T14:00",
  "2023-10-21T15:00",
  "2023-10-21T16:00",
  "2023-10-21T17:00",
  "2023-10-21T18:00",
  "2023-10-21T19:00",
  "2023-10-21T20:00",
  "2023-10-21T21:00",
  "2023-10-21T22:00",
  "2023-10-21T23:00",
  "2023-10-22T00:00",
  "2023-10-22T01:00",
  "2023-10-22T02:00",
  "2023-10-22T03:00",
  "2023-10-22T04:00",
  "2023-10-22T05:00",
  "2023-10-22T06:00",
  "2023-10-22T07:00",
  "2023-10-22T08:00",
  "2023-10-22T09:00",
  "2023-10-22T10:00",
  "2023-10-22T11:00",
  "2023-10-22T12:00",
  "2023-10-22T13:00",
  "2023-10-22T14:00",
  "2023-10-22T15:00",
  "2023-10-22T16:00",
  "2023-10-22T17:00",
  "2023-10-22T18:00",
  "2023-10-22T19:00",
  "2023-10-22T20:00",
  "2023-10-22T21:00",
  "2023-10-22T22:00",
  "2023-10-22T23:00"
],
"temperature_2m": [
  6.0,
  5.9,
  5.7,
  5.2,
  4.9,
  4.9,
  4.8,
  5.2,
  6.3,
  7.9,
  9.2,
  10.3,
  10.7,
  10.6,
  10.5,
  10.3,
  9.7,
  8.9,
  8.5,
  7.6,
  7.0,
  6.8,
  6.5,
  6.1,
  5.8,
  5.5,
  5.3,
  4.9,
  4.7,
  4.6,
  4.2,
  4.2,
  6.1,
  8.1,
  9.8,
  10.7,
  11.1,
  11.4,
  11.5,
  11.2,
  10.2,
  9.0,
  8.0,
  7.1,
  6.7,
  6.4,
  6.0,
  5.5,
  5.2,
  5.0,
  4.8,
  4.5,
  4.1,
  3.9,
  3.7,
  4.3,
  6.2,
  8.1,
  10.0,
  11.4,
  12.2,
  12.6,
  12.3,
  11.8,
  10.7,
  9.1,
  8.0,
  7.2,
  6.7,
  6.2,
  5.9,
  5.6,
  5.4,
  5.3,
  5.4,
  5.4,
  5.5,
  5.6,
  5.7,
  5.7,
  5.9,
  6.3,
  6.7,
  6.9,
  7.2,
  7.4,
  7.7,
  7.8,
  7.8,
  7.9,
  7.8,
  7.8,
  7.8,
  7.7,
  7.6,
  7.4,
  7.1,
  6.7,
  6.2,
  5.6,
  5.0,
  4.4,
  3.9,
  3.7,
  3.7,
  3.9,
  4.3,
  4.9,
  5.4,
  5.8,
  6.0,
  5.9,
  5.4,
  4.7,
  3.9,
  3.0,
  2.1,
  1.4,
  1.0,
  0.8,
  0.6,
  0.3,
  -0.1,
  -0.4,
  -0.6,
  -0.7,
  -0.7,
  -0.6,
  -0.4,
  -0.2,
  0.0,
  0.3,
  0.5,
  0.5,
  0.6,
  0.6,
  0.6,
  0.7,
  0.7,
  0.7,
  0.8,
  0.8,
  0.9,
  0.9,
  1.0,
  1.0,
  1.0,
  1.1,
  1.1,
  1.1,
  1.2,
  1.4,
  1.8,
  2.2,
  2.8,
  3.5,
  3.9,
  4.1,
  4.0,
  3.9,
  3.7,
  3.4,
  3.1,
  2.8,
  2.5,
  2.2,
  1.9,
  1.8
],
"weathercode": [
  3,
  2,
  2,
  1,
  2,
  2,
  3,
  2,
  2,
  2,
  3,
  2,
  2,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  2,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  2,
  2,
  2,
  2,
  2,
  3,
  45,
  45,
  45,
  45,
  1,
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  2,
  2,
  2,
  2,
  1,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  0,
  3,
  1,
  0,
  3,
  0,
  2,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  2,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  61,
  61,
  61,
  61,
  61,
  61,
  61,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  61,
  61,
  61,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  71,
  71,
  71,
  73,
  73,
  73,
  73,
  73,
  73,
  71,
  71,
  71,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  2,
  2,
  2,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  2,
  2
],
"relativehumidity_2m": [
  83,
  83,
  85,
  88,
  90,
  89,
  89,
  88,
  83,
  78,
  70,
  65,
  63,
  64,
  65,
  65,
  70,
  77,
  80,
  86,
  88,
  88,
  91,
  93,
  94,
  94,
  94,
  95,
  97,
  98,
  99,
  100,
  92,
  83,
  74,
  65,
  60,
  58,
  57,
  58,
  69,
  76,
  81,
  85,
  85,
  84,
  87,
  90,
  91,
  92,
  92,
  93,
  94,
  94,
  94,
  93,
  86,
  77,
  71,
  64,
  58,
  52,
  56,
  60,
  64,
  70,
  76,
  80,
  80,
  81,
  82,
  84,
  83,
  83,
  82,
  81,
  80,
  79,
  79,
  81,
  82,
  81,
  81,
  82,
  81,
  80,
  79,
  78,
  79,
  80,
  80,
  81,
  82,
  83,
  83,
  82,
  81,
  80,
  80,
  79,
  78,
  77,
  75,
  70,
  63,
  57,
  54,
  53,
  52,
  50,
  49,
  48,
  48,
  49,
  51,
  56,
  61,
  66,
  68,
  68,
  69,
  72,
  77,
  81,
  85,
  88,
  91,
  92,
  92,
  91,
  90,
  88,
  87,
  88,
  88,
  88,
  89,
  90,
  91,
  92,
  92,
  92,
  92,
  92,
  92,
  92,
  92,
  92,
  92,
  93,
  92,
  90,
  88,
  85,
  81,
  77,
  74,
  74,
  77,
  79,
  81,
  84,
  87,
  90,
  93,
  95,
  96,
  96
],
"windspeed_10m": [
  13.7,
  13.7,
  12.6,
  11.9,
  11.3,
  11.2,
  11.4,
  12.3,
  12.2,
  11.2,
  12.8,
  12.5,
  11.9,
  10.5,
  10.8,
  9.9,
  7.9,
  6.5,
  5.2,
  4.7,
  4.0,
  4.0,
  3.8,
  3.3,
  2.6,
  1.8,
  3.1,
  2.9,
  2.4,
  1.8,
  2.9,
  1.5,
  1.1,
  2.1,
  2.0,
  3.6,
  4.5,
  4.1,
  4.3,
  3.8,
  3.8,
  4.0,
  3.6,
  3.1,
  3.3,
  3.3,
  3.8,
  3.5,
  3.1,
  3.3,
  3.7,
  3.5,
  3.7,
  4.0,
  4.4,
  4.3,
  5.8,
  6.0,
  6.6,
  8.4,
  10.0,
  11.3,
  11.0,
  9.6,
  9.1,
  8.8,
  8.8,
  9.9,
  10.3,
  11.0,
  11.4,
  11.0,
  12.1,
  10.3,
  12.6,
  10.9,
  12.3,
  12.6,
  13.3,
  13.0,
  13.0,
  11.5,
  12.6,
  11.9,
  11.9,
  11.9,
  13.1,
  13.7,
  14.3,
  14.0,
  14.8,
  15.6,
  17.1,
  17.9,
  18.3,
  18.8,
  18.9,
  19.1,
  19.1,
  19.0,
  18.7,
  18.1,
  18.1,
  18.5,
  19.5,
  20.4,
  20.6,
  20.6,
  20.6,
  20.9,
  21.3,
  21.7,
  22.4,
  22.9,
  23.3,
  23.7,
  24.0,
  24.1,
  24.1,
  23.7,
  23.3,
  22.9,
  22.2,
  21.6,
  21.5,
  21.9,
  22.1,
  21.6,
  20.6,
  19.8,
  18.6,
  17.1,
  16.3,
  15.3,
  13.5,
  12.0,
  10.0,
  7.7,
  6.0,
  4.3,
  3.0,
  1.8,
  0.8,
  1.3,
  2.6,
  3.5,
  4.5,
  5.2,
  5.1,
  4.8,
  4.8,
  5.7,
  7.2,
  8.2,
  9.0,
  9.5,
  9.8,
  9.7,
  8.9,
  8.4,
  7.6,
  7.0,
  6.5,
  6.0,
  5.9,
  5.9,
  5.9,
  5.5
],
"pressure_msl": [
  1019.1,
  1019.1,
  1019.1,
  1019.5,
  1019.0,
  1019.6,
  1019.5,
  1019.7,
  1020.2,
  1020.3,
  1020.4,
  1020.1,
  1020.1,
  1020.3,
  1019.8,
  1020.3,
  1020.1,
  1020.8,
  1021.1,
  1021.4,
  1021.5,
  1021.8,
  1022.1,
  1022.1,
  1022.0,
  1021.9,
  1021.9,
  1022.0,
  1022.1,
  1022.0,
  1022.3,
  1022.8,
  1023.0,
  1023.2,
  1023.0,
  1022.5,
  1021.9,
  1021.2,
  1020.6,
  1020.7,
  1020.8,
  1020.9,
  1020.6,
  1020.5,
  1020.4,
  1020.4,
  1020.1,
  1019.9,
  1019.7,
  1019.3,
  1018.9,
  1018.5,
  1018.3,
  1018.1,
  1018.2,
  1018.1,
  1017.8,
  1017.3,
  1016.8,
  1016.1,
  1015.2,
  1014.4,
  1013.8,
  1013.4,
  1012.4,
  1012.2,
  1011.9,
  1011.4,
  1011.0,
  1010.4,
  1009.7,
  1009.2,
  1008.1,
  1007.9,
  1006.7,
  1006.2,
  1005.7,
  1005.1,
  1004.9,
  1004.8,
  1004.5,
  1004.4,
  1004.1,
  1003.7,
  1003.5,
  1003.1,
  1002.9,
  1002.5,
  1002.5,
  1002.7,
  1002.8,
  1003.0,
  1003.3,
  1003.5,
  1003.5,
  1003.5,
  1003.5,
  1003.5,
  1003.6,
  1003.8,
  1004.2,
  1004.6,
  1005.0,
  1005.1,
  1005.2,
  1005.1,
  1004.9,
  1004.6,
  1004.3,
  1004.0,
  1003.7,
  1003.5,
  1003.4,
  1003.3,
  1003.1,
  1002.8,
  1002.4,
  1001.9,
  1001.3,
  1000.5,
  999.8,
  999.0,
  998.2,
  997.5,
  996.9,
  996.3,
  995.8,
  995.4,
  995.0,
  994.7,
  994.4,
  994.0,
  993.8,
  993.8,
  993.6,
  993.5,
  993.6,
  993.8,
  994.1,
  994.4,
  994.8,
  995.1,
  995.4,
  995.7,
  996.0,
  996.4,
  996.8,
  997.3,
  997.9,
  998.6,
  999.3,
  1000.1,
  1001.0,
  1001.9,
  1002.6,
  1003.3,
  1004.0,
  1004.7,
  1005.5,
  1006.3,
  1007.3,
  1008.4,
  1009.4,
  1010.3,
  1011.2,
  1012.0,
  1012.8,
  1013.5
]
}
```

data class  WeatherData(
val time:LocalDateTime,
val temperatureCelsius: Double,
val pressure: Double,
val windSpeed: Double,
val humidity: Double,
val weatherType: WeatherType
)

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideWeatherApi():WeatherApi{

```
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.open-meteo.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create()
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the JSON that is returned from the server and compare that with your data class definition? They do not match.

Comment: I am using only the hourly data from the Json

Comment: The error indicates that the parsing code is expecting a JSON array `[...]` but it is seeing a JSON object `{...}` instead. So you have a mismatch between the data and what the parsing code expects. I see nowhere in your code where you explicitly indicate that you are trying to parse only the hourly data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have model class, generated like this.

**WeatherDTO.kt**

```
data class WeatherDTO(

    @field:SerializedName("elevation")
    val elevation: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("hourly_units")
    val hourlyUnits: HourlyUnits? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("generationtime_ms")
    val generationtimeMs: Double? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("timezone_abbreviation")
    val timezoneAbbreviation: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("timezone")
    val timezone: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("latitude")
    val latitude: Double? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("utc_offset_seconds")
    val utcOffsetSeconds: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("hourly")
    val hourly: Hourly? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("longitude")
    val longitude: Double? = null
)
```

**Hourly.kt**

```
data class Hourly(

    @field:SerializedName("pressure_msl")
    val pressureMsl: List<Double> = emptyList(),

    @field:SerializedName("temperature_2m")
    val temperature2m: List<Double> = emptyList,

    @field:SerializedName("relativehumidity_2m")
    val relativehumidity2m: List<Double> = emptyList,

    @field:SerializedName("weathercode")
    val weathercode: List<Double> = emptyList,

    @field:SerializedName("windspeed_10m")
    val windspeed10m: List<Double> = emptyList,

    @field:SerializedName("time")
    val time: List<Double> = emptyList
)
```

**HourlyUnits.kt**

```
data class HourlyUnits(
    @field:SerializedName("pressure_msl")
    val pressureMsl: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("temperature_2m")
    val temperature2m: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("relativehumidity_2m")
    val relativehumidity2m: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("weathercode")
    val weathercode: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("windspeed_10m")
    val windspeed10m: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("time")
    val time: String? = null
)
```

As your return type from the api call seems perfect. This should work fine.
Or you can try adding a ScalarsConvertor to the retrofit to check the response received in String format to better understand the scenario.

> **Note: You must add ScalarsConvertor before the GsonConvertor in Retrofit.**

Comment: Yes, it should I think. Or you can just comment the Json Adapter for the debug and testing purpose and put the ScalarsConvertor. Just to check the Response received.

Comment: The tutorial I followed used only the hourly Json data will it work if I follow that method

Comment: Can you post the exact models, retrofit instance, and the methods you are using. And also the Logcat if you are receiving any data.
And are you using the GsonConvertor? or some other convertor can you please add that too.

Comment: I am not receiving any data it shows the error in expected begin object error in logcat, I have edited the question to show the things you asked